# Как отправить массив ввода html в Django?

Tags: python, html, django

Есть html форма, в которой несколько input заполняются так:

`{% for key,value in request.session.cart.items %}`

`<input type="name" class="product-title-cart" name="productTitle[]" value="{{value.name}}" disabled>`

`{% endfor %}`

как я могу получить значение этих input на стороне пайтона?

Я пробовал так:

`request.POST.getlist('productTitle[]')` - возвращает пустой массив
`request.POST.get("productTitle[]")` - возвращает None
`request.POST.get("productTitle")` - возвращает None

Comment: Для начала посмотрите какой html получится на фронте. у меня смутное подозрение что получится фигня

Comment: ну а так попробуй забрать данные через `request.POST` во `views.py`